# Java + JPA: Search User in Database By first and last name return too many results. Is there a better way?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, jpa-2.0

Right now my implementation is like this, so if the user type is `Peter Smith`, then I would a split on the query string like this:

```
String[] name = searchQuery.split(" "); //searchQuery is type String
```

then I would loop through `name array`, and for each `name`, I match it against first name and last name fields in my db as below

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.findUserByName",
    query="select c from User c where c.fname LIKE :param OR c.lname LIKE :param"),

public List<User> findUser(String searchParam){
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findUserByName");
    query.setParameter("param", "%" + searchParam + "%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

however, if I do this, it return too many results (Every thing related to Peter will be display and everything related to Smith will be as well). Is there a better way to do this?

I am using EclipseLink btw

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I'd use the Criteria API instead. Here's a sample implementation:

```
public List<User> findUsersByName(final String firstName,
    final String lastName){

    final boolean hasFirst = firstName != null && firstName.length() > 0;
    // if you use Apache Commons / Lang, do it like this:
    // final boolean hasFirst = StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName);

    final boolean hasLast = lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0;
    if(!hasFirst && !hasLast){
        // or throw IllegalArgumentException
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    final Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
    if(hasFirst && hasLast){
        query.where(cb.and(
            likeExpression(cb, root,"lname", lastName),
            likeExpression(cb, root, "fname", firstName)
            ));
    } else if(hasFirst){
        query.where(likeExpression(cb, root,"fname", firstName));
    } else{
        query.where(likeExpression(cb, root,"lname", lastName));
    }
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}

private static Predicate likeExpression(final CriteriaBuilder cb,
    final Root<User> root,
    final String path, String parameter){
    return cb.like(root.<String> get(path), "*"+parameter.trim()+"*");
}
```

Now you can easily create overloaded versions of this method:

```
public List<User> findUsersByFullName(final String fullName){
    final String[] parts = fullName.split("\\s+");
    if(parts.length != 2){
        // probably you should assemble first name from all parts
        // except the last, but I'm lazy
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad name: " + fullName);
    }
    return findUsersByName(parts[0], parts[1]);
}

public List<User> findUsersByLastName(final String lastName){
    return findUsersByName(null, lastName);
}

public List<User> findUsersByFirstName(final String firstName){
    return findUsersByName(firstName, null);
}
```

**Reference:**

- **Java EE 6 Tutorial: [Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)**

Comment: Awesome, I will give it a try. Probably will have couple questions for you. Thank you. +1

Comment: Is there a reason why you use final to all of your variables?

Comment: @Harry a) it's good practice to document that variables are not re-assigned b) it lets the compiler optimize code. example here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/518466/Performance/java/Compiler-optimization-final-variables

Comment: I have eclipse's Save Actions configured to automatically add final to parameters, local variables and fields if possible

Comment: That sound nice, you know if netbean have that feature?

Comment: @Harry nope, I've never used NetBeans

Comment: I copy and paste your code to test it. I try `findUsersByFirstName`, and it does not work for me, it return 0 users, even if I type the exact first name of that user. I am not sure I understand this statement `return cb.like(root.<String> get(path), "*"+parameter.trim()+"*");`, I know it suppose check if either `fname` or `lname`, look like what I type in, but I cant understand the syntax. Can you help me? Thank you